# android studio: creating android splash screen

Tags: java, android

Hi i am trying to create a splash screen for android and the background that i want is this. [Splash background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Veod.png)

I want to do this by setting the styles and themes for android rather than using a thread to run the splash screen as i heard it is better to do that.

So this is my layouts below:

styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>


<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

    <item
        name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
</style>
```

android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.recouture">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

SplashScrenActivity.java

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,MainActivity.class));

        finish();
    }
}
```

Problem is with my splash.xml layout inside my drawable. I do not know how to set more than one image in my splash.xml as the tutorials online only teach you how to set splash screens with a single logo.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/colorSplash" />
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/logo"
        />
</item>
```

I have the the logos imported into my android studio:

[logo1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA1D4.png)

[logo2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QKDX.png)

[logo3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAWgx.png)

Appreciate any help !

Comment: you need to make your splash screen one image using an image editor or something, i don't yhink if there's other ways

Comment: All right thanks mate !